# New license for Kendo UI

Tags: angular2-template

We have existing license for Kendo UI, angularJS 1.5 version. We want to upgrade the our current project to angular 2+. 
Can we use existing Kendo UI license to get new Kendo UI for angular 2+ support? Or need to purchase new license for angular 2?

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upgrade to the angular 2+ product from our suite with your current license. This is also described in the [Licensing and Pricing section here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/)

In addition, I would suggest you go through the Getting Started section, where detailed information about the usage of the Kendo UI for Angular is provided:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/